# UITableViewCellをPushしたときに、Cellの下側に新たにテキストエリアを表示したい

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uitableview

[環境] iOS 7.0 or more than XCode 6.0.1

添付画像のように、UITableViewCellをPUSHしたときに、Cellの下側に新たにテキストエリアを表示したいです。上手く情報にあたることができず、こちらで聞いてみました。
アコーディオンという、セクション毎にセルの表示、非表示という言葉には突き当たりましたが、若干見たい情報とは違うといった状況です。実装方法や、githubのlibraryなど、ご存知でしたら教えていただけるとありがたいです。[image]

※英語版のstackoverflowはときどき使います。
※添付画像について、不必要な情報は非表示にしております。

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`UITableViewDelegate`に`tableView:heightForRowAtIndexPath:`というセルの高さを指定するメソッドがあるので、それと`UITableViewDataSource`の`tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:`を実装して、`reloadData`や`reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:withRowAnimation:`をコールして変更したい行を再作成すれば実現できると思います。

Comment: ご回答ありがとうございます。また、実装イメージができました。本当にありがとうございます。もう１点質問ですが表示する長さについて、固定値ではなく文字数に応じて可変で長さを調整したいと思いますが、実装方法についてイメージがわきません。UILabelの長さを調節する機能を使用して、可変で値を取得する形になりますか？

Comment: @tomojiro `NSString`の拡張である`boundingRectWithSize:options:attributes:context:`とかで推定可能です。

Comment: 貴重な情報ありがとうございます。こちらで試してみたいと思います。
本当にありがとうございました。